# ASP.NET loses user context when connecting to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication, ado.net

In ASP.NET, we have an application that prompts users for their AD credentials using Basic Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation.

The application then connects to SQL Server with the following connection string

```cs
SqlClient.SqlConnection cnn = new SqlClient.SqlConnection();
cnn.ConnectionString = 
  "Server=" + MenuServer + ";" + 
  "Database= " + MenuDatabase + ";" + 
  "Trusted_Connection=Yes;" + 
  "Pooling = False;";
cnn.Open();
```

99% of the time, this passes along the user context just fine, but sporadically we get the following error from SQL Server:

> Login failed for user '*WebServerName*$'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided

Meaning that it has been unable to pass along the user credentials and instead defaulted to the IIS worker process. Interestingly, when we catch the error, the current user will still be accurately recorded with the following code:

```cs
string userName = Environment.UserName;
```

**Questions**:

- What user context does the Integrated Security pass along to the database?
- Is it possible to programmatically check the user before calling `cnn.Open()` to confirm we have a real user?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are using ORM Mappers, e.g. Entity Framework or NHibernate (I have experuienced this with NHibernate). It is because the mapping framework uses Lazy Evaluation: it doesn't get all the data from the database until you ask for it. For example, if you are getting a list of objects each of which contains a further list of objects (e.g. Customer contains a list of Invoice), it won't get the Invoice objects until you actually use them.

If you don't use then until binding them to an aspx control and you do that in the aspx page (not in e.g. the PageLoad event), then the life-cycle of an aspx page means that it looks at the sub-list after your code has run and any impersonation you are doing has ended - this under the IIS account.

You can prevent this happening by either preventing lazy evaluation (generally not a good idea), or by making sure that you touch each of the lists you'll need the page to use in your code, under your impersonated account.

```
for each (Customer c in customers)
{
    int i = c.Invoices.Count; // make sure that they do get retrieved.
}
```

Comment: Simon, thanks, but I don't think that is the issue.  For 1, we're just using a .NET business library as our ORM layer, so it's not lazily evaluating anything.  For 2, the error is thrown as soon as we call `Open` on the connection, and we're always seeing this error (when we do see it) immediately on application launch when it's initializing the session.  There might be some weird race condition here to get the authenticated user established before making the database call, but simply invoking immediately won't change anything.

Comment: What does System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name return when you do the Connection.Open()?

Comment: The bug only flashes up sporadically in the wild, but I'm going to add logging for the following variables to see which are being populated: `Environment.UserName`, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, `System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().UserName`, 
`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`.  I was asking the question to see if someone knew ahead of time which identity would likely be passed along to SQL Server.

Comment: I think it uses WindowsIdentity.CurrentUser, but could be wrong. Good luck! Let us know what happens!